# Creating a subclass to represent a banking account in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that will use an Account class and from there create two subclasses, checking and savings that extends the parent Account class. I believe I have this portion of the code completed.

Now here is the two subclasses:

(Checking)

```
public class Checking extends Account {

    double overdraftLimit = 5000;

    public void withdraw (double w) {

        if (balance - w < overdraftLimit) {
            System.out.println("The exceeds the overdraft limit of $5000");
        } else {
            super.withdraw(w);
        }
    } // End of withdraw method

} // End of Checking.
```

My problem lies within the final set of instructions. When I go thru my program and attempt to exceed the overdraft limit nothing happens. What could I do to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: Final set of instructions: 
a) Creates 2 objects - a Saving Account and a Checking Account. Get user inputs for
account information that is needed to create these 2 objects.
￼￼￼
b) Get user input for an amount to be withdrawn from the Checking Account and an amount to be deposited to the Checking Account. Make sure the overdraft restrictions work.
c) Similarly, withdraw and deposit from and into the Saving Account also.

Comment: You just removed almost all of the code without making a good small reproducible example. Looking at your current code - if you attempt to exceed the overdraft limit and nothing happens, isn't that exactly what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
You are withdrawing from the normal Account, without checking

```
sa.withdraw(withdrawAmount);
```

Try `no.withdraw(withdrawAmount);`
But notice, that you create an empty Checking-Account without the input data.

**Original post**

Your are creating and Object of class `Account`, which of course does not check your overdraft.
To use your new Subclass change

```
Account sa = new Account(accountNumber, accountBalance, interestRate);
```

to

```
Account sa = new Checking(accountNumber, accountBalance, interestRate);
```

Make sure, that the consturctors exist in your subclass, as it is required in your task!

Java always checks first in the class itself, if the method exists, then in the superclasses. But if you dont even create your subclass, you cant use their methods, of course!